Copying a file to a GCP VM at speed of 150 KiB/s
I'm trying to copy a few tar files (100MB, 200MB) to my Debian 12 e2-micro GCP VM, using Filezilla
( I also tried using MobaxTerm, exactly the same speed)
The upload speed is 150 KiB/s
Am I doing something wrong, or is it supposed to be like that ?

we cannot define the upload speed as it may differ in various types like network speed, configuration.
As you are using e2-micro which is used for general-purpose machines which have 2 vcpus, 1GB memory.
Normally it will have less cpu and memory and has low Network performance compared to others.
The upload speed can also be affected by factors like the file size, network latency, and the speed of your local internet connection and if you are using Filezilla google cloud cannot promise you the mentioned speed or performance, If possible try using CLI or Cloud storage.
You can find the different machine performance.

I'm using the cheapest possible (7.99) e2-micro, on aws (also N Virginia) t2.micro I can copy this file in 1 second with Mobaxterm and filezilla, so it's not latency

tried gcloud compute scp:
| 11628 kB | 140.1 kB/s | ETA: 00:18:39 |   6%

then it might be an issue can you create a new Issue Tracker thread describing your issue. If you have paid support try create an issue
